# SQL Server stored procedures dynamic SQL with multiple different where clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause, dynamic-sql

Input CASE1=wen @type is NULL-> WHERE c.Date_Redeemed BETWEEN @Start AND @End-- this should execute

If CASE2=wen @start,@end is NULL->WHERE c.Type=@type-- this should execute
CASE 3=wen @value is null->WHERE c.Date_Redeemed BETWEEN @Start AND @End AND c.Type=@type this should execute

CASE4=wen @marketclass is NULL->WHERE c.Date_Redeemed BETWEEN @Start AND @End AND c.Type=@type AND c.ordervalue BETWEEN @price1 AND @price2

VAR=@type,@start,@price1,@marketclass if eithr of var is NULL dynamicaly other input where condition has to execute like diff combination of input comes

```
WHERE
   (c.Type = @type AND o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end) OR
   (@start IS NULL AND c.Type = @type) OR
   (@type IS NULL and o.Date_of_Purchase BETWEEN @start AND @end) OR
   (@start IS NULL AND @type IS NULL)
```

- if both are provided, only rows where type and date match are returned,
- if type is not provided, date is used,
- if date not provided type is used and
- if nothing provided all rows return. To make no rows return, remove the last predicate

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sample 
    @start DATE, @end DATE, 
    @type VARCHAR(5),
    @price1 MONEY, @price2 MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL= 'SELECT DISTINCT o.O_Id,o.Sale_Price,o.Order_Line_Id,Private_Band,c.Date_of_Purchase,c.Date_Redeemed,c.Credit_Memo,c.Credit_Memo_Created_Date,c.Credit_Memo_Approved_Date,
    c.Type,c.Points_Issued,o.Date_of_Purchase FROM Order_Details o ,Transaction_Historys c WHERE -1='-1''
    IF @type IS NOT NULL AND @type <> 0            
    SET @SQL = @SQL+ 'c.Type = @type'
    ELSE
    IF @start IS NOT NULL AND @start <> 0
    SET @SQL = @SQL+ 'c.Date_redeemed BETWEEN @start AND @end'    

    EXECUTE dbo.sample @type='Earn',@start='2010-02-10',@end='2020-04-11'
END
```

Comment: pls help me to create dynamic sp for above cases

Comment: add EXEC @SQL at the end of your stored procedure

Comment: Can you rewrite the code for cases with EXEC sql as im new to to I need to know the skeleton of dynamic sql pls @Sanpas

Comment: Here's a solid introduction. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Having looked through this, I'm actually kind of reluctant to post this answer, because there's so many things wrong with this:

- prone to SQL injection;
- using antiquated JOIN syntax;
- clunky logic.

The simple answer is that sometimes just because you CAN do something in SQL doesn't mean you actually SHOULD.

Anyway, I think is closer to what you wanted?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[sample] (
    @start DATE, 
    @end DATE, 
    @type VARCHAR(5),
    @price1 NUMERIC(9,2),
    @price2 NUMERIC(9,2))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(1024);
    SELECT @sql = N'
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            o.O_Id,
            o.Sale_Price,
            o.Order_Line_Id,
            Private_Band, --alias?
            c.Date_of_Purchase,
            c.Date_Redeemed,
            c.Credit_Memo,
            c.Credit_Memo_Created_Date,
            c.Credit_Memo_Approved_Date,
            c.Type,
            c.Points_Issued,
            o.Date_of_Purchase 
        FROM 
            Order_Details o, 
            Transaction_Historys c'; --Join condition?!
    DECLARE @constraint VARCHAR(1024) = '';
    IF @type IS NOT NULL AND @type != 0            
    BEGIN
        SELECT @constraint = CONCAT(' WHERE c.Type = ''', @type, '''');
    END;
    IF @start IS NOT NULL AND @end IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @constraint = CONCAT(@constraint, 
            CASE WHEN @constraint = '' THEN ' WHERE ' ELSE ' AND ' END, 
            ' c.Date_redeemed BETWEEN ''', 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @start, 112), 
            ''' AND ''', 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @end, 112)),
            '''';    
    END;
    SELECT @sql = CONCAT(@sql, @constraint);
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
GO
EXEC dbo.[sample] @type = 'Earn', @start = '20100210', @end = '20200411', @price1 = NULL, @price2 = NULL;
```

I made quite a few changes here:

- I couldn't bring myself to use a `MONEY` type, so change it back if you really want it;
- I added some comments to your script ;)
- I sort of fixed the actual issue, that you need to cope with one or two or even no constraints being passed in.

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.sample, Line 30
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Earn' to data type int. I get this error

Comment: In your database, `type` must be an INT? But you set it up so you pass in `Earn`, which is a string.

Comment: No type is varchar(5) in db and so only variable I declared @type also as varchar(5)